# Zoom with Control+Mouse-wheel in Ubuntu 22.04 (Gnome)

Tags: gnome, mouse, 22.04, zooming, mouse-wheel

In most applications, <kbd>Control</kbd>+Mouse-wheel allows one to zoom in or out (e.g. Firefox, LibreOffice, Evince, etc.). After upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, Gnome seems to catch the event and switches to left/right workspace on <kbd>Control</kbd>+Mouse-wheel, and the application doesn't receive it. As a consequence, zooming with <kbd>Control</kbd>+Mouse-wheel doesn't work.

I checked the keyboard shortcuts in the "Keyboard" section of `gnome-control-center`, but as the name suggests it contains only *keyboard* shortcuts, not mouse-wheel related ones.

This is not the default behavior, since I'm not getting it on another account on the same machine.

In any case, how can I get back the old behavior, i.e. let the <kbd>Control</kbd>+Mouse-wheel reach the applications (and allow me to zoom in/out)? Or any idea where to search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration comes from the [dconf](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf.html.en) configuration database, more precisely the `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/mouse-button-modifier` key. In my case, it was set to a string containing `<Control>` (in addition to other modifiers), setting back to the default value restored a correct behavior.

Resetting to the default can be done graphically using [`dconf-editor`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DconfEditor) (toggle the `Use default value` switch to `on`):

[image]

If you prefer the command-line, then `gsettings` is the answer:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier
```