How to turn on the function of `Ctrl`+ "Mouse Wheel Zoom" in `gnome-terminal` in ubuntu22.04?
I want my terminal to zoom in and zoom out with Ctrl + mouse wheel zoom.
As a newbee in ubuntu, I have attempted the solution provided in this link, with the configuration of gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier in my Ubuntu22.04 on VMware, but it still doesn't work.
Is there any official documentation describe the relate configuration?
The release details provided by lsb_release -a is as follows:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

I am not sure WHERE to find the option System Settings and Details in the link.
I can only find the relate infomation in Settings > About >


My VSCode can zoom in/out with Ctrl + WHEELs well, but the gnome terminal couldn't.
What I ideal result is “Press the Ctrl” and I can zoom in/out smoothly with MOUSE-WHEEL as below:

It is a continuous change, not one click at a time to select the zoom in/out.

Sorry for I mention  some other terminal that confused, I have modified that and will append the details of my release.

This question is similar to: Zoom with Control+Mouse-wheel in Ubuntu 22.04 (Gnome). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks to yr reply. I HAVE follow the link you mention, and I have change the gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences mouse-button-modifier as the video showed. Is there other matrials and infomation should I provide?

Mouse zoom seems not available in terminal. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/566465/345853 but there are short cut keys you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/54303088

Thanks to yr reply, but it seemed strange in the previos link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418320/zoom-with-controlmouse-wheel-in-ubuntu-22-04-gnome, is that I mistook the requirement of that question? Or how can that answer receive 3 UP?
